# ALVisualCompass and deviation count

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I'm trying to use ALVisualCompass, I have followed an example (in C++) and rewrite the important parts to python. But my attempt to load 'VisualCompass/Deviation' from memory ends up with 'None' response. Methods like getMatchingQuality works. Is there something special needed in order to get deviation count?

Excerption from my code (using STK but I have also less readable version using naoqi directly)

```
self.videoname = self.s.ALVideoDevice.subscribeCamera(VIDEO, 0, VGA, 3, FPS)
self.s.ALVisualCompass.enableReferenceRefresh(True)
self.s.ALVisualCompass.setResolution(VGA)
self.s.ALVisualCompass.subscribe(COMPASS_TEST)

refImage = self.s.ALVisualCompass.getReferenceImage()
newImage = self.s.ALVideoDevice.getImageRemote(self.videoname)
```

I can show both refImage and newImage as pictures. From the following debug info, only 'VisualCompass/Deviation' returns None. The rest of the results looks relevant.

```
print self.s.ALVisualCompass.getMatchingQuality()
print self.s.ALMemory.getData("VisualCompass/Deviation")
print self.s.ALMemory.getData("VisualCompass/Match")
```

NAOqi version: 2.5.10.7

Comment: Do you look at potential raising of this event: "VisualCompass/InvalidReference". If yes and not raised, then could you post the code, and indicate your robot model and naoqi version you use?

Comment: @AlexandreMazel thanks. This event is not raised at all, I'm also able to show the reference image. I will update the question with code.